# Allow users to unsubscribe

Tags: 7, users, emails

I'm working on a Drupal 7 site that has Simplenews and a custom registration process. The registration allows the user to subscribe to the newsletter, but once logged in there is nowhere to unsubscribe.

How do I go about creating a new page with features allowing the user to change their subscription?

I've search far and wide but can't get a concrete answer.

Comment: Which version you are saying about D7 or D8?

Comment: I'm using Drupal 7